# C# определить является ли процесс фоновым

Tags: c#, процесс

Получаю список все процессов командой

```
Process[] allProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
```

Далее через foreach достаю каждый процесс по отдельности. Как определить является ли процесс фоновым или же это приложение? Так же интересуют альтернативные способы получения информации о процессах. Возможно через вин апи можно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UpdAte: 
Не идеально конечно, но лучше чем ничего. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя foreach перебирает примерно полминуты. (Возможно у меня слишком много процессов).
Есть ли более быстрый способ?

Comment: Это просто фишка диспетчера задач делить каким-то образом процессы на 2 категории. Реально процессы не бывают фоновыми. Подумай, какие процессы ты хочешь выделить и какой признак их характеризует. Сомневаюсь, что ты хочешь сделать тупой клон диспетчера задач.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте свойство [MainWindowHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Process[] allProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var p in allProcess)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName + " " + (p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero ? "[background]": "[non-background]"));
}
```

Если его значение равно нулю (IntPtr.Zero), то процесс является фоновым.

---

> Хотя foreach перебирает примерно полминуты. (Возможно у меня слишком много процессов). Есть ли более быстрый способ?

Попробуйте распараллелить поиск процессов, например при помощи методов класса [Parallel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx), либо PLINQ.

Comment: Кажется, мимо... UPDATE: Или нет... Но их же можно развернуть.

Comment: @Qwertiy что вы хотели этим сказать? Безусловно, можно еще действовать через WinAPI, но я только что проверил это решение и оно соответствует показаниям диспетчера задач.

Comment: В диспетчере задач у части "приложений" есть стрелочка, разворачивающая пачку вложенных процессов. Они чему соответствуют? Окно есть только у главного же?

Comment: @Qwertiy окно да, у только главного, все остальные (вложенные) просто переносятся в раздел фоновых. Например, если взять приложение Google Chrome - родительский процесс будет приложением, все остальные (их можно посмотреть ПКМ -> Подробно) будут фоновыми. При этом в выводе программы мы действительно увидим, что один из chrome.exe - UI процесс, все остальные chrome.exe - фоновые.